# Use classes of dynamically loaded html with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically loaded page with divs of class product. Jquery doesn't see this class with the code below. When I click on product divs it doesn't do anything. However clicl on nav-element works fine. Any way to make it work with it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav-element").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
    $(".nav-element").css("background", "#fff");
    $("#"+id).css("background", "#A4CFBE");
    $(".content-white").load(id+".html");
    });
    $(".content-white").load("nav-element1.html");
$(".product").click(function(){
    alert("poop");
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a delegated event handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-element").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
        $(".nav-element").css("background", "#fff");
        $("#" + id).css("background", "#A4CFBE");
        $(".content-white").load(id + ".html");
    });
    $(".content-white").load("nav-element1.html");

    // event delegation to the closest static element
    $(".content-white").on('click', ".product", function () {
        alert("poop");
    });
});
```

Comment: Accepted because adeneo answered first.

Comment: @user1380398 - Actually, Satpal posted an answer first, but it was just a general "use delegation" answer, I posted the first answer with working code.

Answer (score 4):

*a dynamically loaded page with divs of class product*

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container. Here its `".content-white"`

Example

```
$(".content-white").on('click', '.product', function () {
    alert("poop");
});
```