# Use classes of dynamically loaded html with Jquery. Continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Continue of question [Use classes of dynamically loaded html with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499700/use-classes-of-dynamically-loaded-html-with-jquery)

```
$(".content-white").on('click', ".product", function () {
    var id = $(".product").attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

How can I get an element with class product to get it's id?

Comment: I *highly* recommend to read [the jQuery tutorial about event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/): *"In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )`, often following this idiom: `var $this = $( this );`"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this` to refer to the targeted element within the event handler

```
$(".content-white").on('click', ".product", function () {
    var id = this.id;//this here refers to the dom element which was targeted by the handler
    alert(id);
});
```

[Inside the Event Handling Function](http://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/)